# ¿como puedo controlar el volumen con la pantalla de android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

hola amigos programadores como están espero que muy bien

tengo un problema con una app que estoy realizando para la Universidad 
la cual tiene que controlar el volumen mediante la pantalla, es decir que si yo presiono la pantalla para arriba o abajo el volumen del dispositivo suba o baje
el problema es que no e podido capturar el toque de forma vertical 
alguien me puede ayudar en eso

Comment: Bienvenido, reformula la pregunta ya que tienes otra muy similar, es la puedes dejar como controlar el volumen

Comment: Añade el codigo de donde te esta fallando y podremos ayudarte

Answer (score 2):

Debes implementar  el `onTouchEvent()` en el Activity.

Despues sobreescribes el `onTouchEvent()`.

```
private String TAG = GestureActivity.class.getSimpleName();
float initialX, initialY;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    int action = event.getActionMasked();

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = event.getX();
            initialY = event.getY();

            Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float finalX = event.getX();
            float finalY = event.getY();

            Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");

            if (initialX < finalX) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialX > finalX) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialY < finalY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
            }

            if (initialY > finalY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            Log.d(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Capturas el evento touch en tu view

```
class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(action));

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Y este por ejemplo tu view.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // have same code as onTouchEvent() (for the Activity) above

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(action));

        return true;
    }
});
```

Para explicación más detallada puedes visitar este link.

[Using onTouchEvent() and View.OnTouchListener Interface with MotionEvent to Detect Common Gestures Like Tap and Swipes on Android](http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/)

Answer (score 0):

No he entendido muy bien, pero si lo que quieres es subir o bajar el volumen al deslizar hacia arriba o hacia abajo en la pantalla, lo que tienes que hacer es detectar un "Gesture".
Para ello, registra un GestureDetector tal y como se explica en https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html. También puedes estudiar algunos ejemplos similares como https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981337/detect-swipe-gesture-in-fragment